# Displaying a string backwards using substring

Tags: java, substring

I have here a method that displays a string backward.

```
public static String ReverseStr(String backward) {
       String newString = "";
       for (int i=0; i<backward.length(); i++) {
          newString = backward.charAt(i) + newString;
       }
       return newString;
}
```

It works properly but I'd like to do it in another way, that is, using a  `for`  loop, getting each character in the string using  `substring`  method with two parameters, starting with the last character then concatenates that one-character substring with the new string each time through the loop. 
 
I tried this:

```
public static String ReverseStr(String backward) {
       String newString = "";
       for (int i=0; i>backward.length(); i--) {
          String subChar = backward.substring(backward.length()-1);
          newString += subChar;
       }
       return newString;
}
```

But when I run the program, it displays nothing. Please help me fix the code. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you are asking too many questions for your own good.  You need to learn to figure these things out for yourself.  You won't become an effective programmer unless you do.

Comment: I agree with Stephen. A few hours spent looking into the javadoc of the standard packages and trying things wouldn't be lost time.

Answer (score 3):

If this is not a homework, then use StringBuilder class and reverse() method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()

If this is a homework do it by yourself.

Comment: Hello Rafael! I didn't know there were such class and method. Thanks. I'm new in Java and I want to practice different styles.

Comment: Hi, as you are studying Java I recommend to check for Java classes source code too. It is a good source for learning purposes. Check file src.zip that is located in folder where you have Java installed. Unzip it and study the source code of standard java classes.

Answer (score 2):

The loop never executes due to wrong control condition:

```
for (int i=0; i>backward.length(); i--)
```

It starts from `0` and continues until `i` is greater than `length` (which is never true as `length` is always at least `0`). You *probably* meant:

```
for (int i=backward.length(); i>=0; i--)
```

Once you manage to fix your code, consider using `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating to `String`. And once you manage to use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), you'll discover handy [`reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) method:

```
return new StringBuilder(backward).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you, Tomasz! You are right haha silly me. But when I run the code, for example I input "hello", it outputs "ooooo".

Comment: @FirstLady: this `backward.substring(backward.length()-1);` is incorrect, figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is messed up, it will never run since you have the wrong condition, change it to:

```
 for (int i=backward.length(); i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: Thank you, ftom2! But when I run the code, for example I input "hello", it outputs "ooooo".

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String strtorev = "Test Code";
        String newString = "";
        int len = strtorev.length();
        System.out.println(len);
        for(int i =0;i<len;i++)
        {
            String subChar = strtorev.substring(strtorev.length()-1-i,strtorev.length()-i);
            newString += subChar;
            System.out.println(newString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should `StringBuilder`. The following code should work as you expect.

```
public static String ReverseStr(String backward)
{
   String newString = "";
   StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(backward);
   for (int i=0; i>backward.length(); i--) //backward.length() may be replaced with sb.length()
   {
      String subChar = sb.charAt(i); //Replace `substring()` with `charAt()`
      newString += subChar;
   }
   return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String ReverseStr(String backward) {

       String newString = "";

       for (int i=backward.length()-1; i>=0; i--) 
          newString+ = backward.charAt(i);

       return newString;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use recursion to reverse a String

```
public class ReverseStringTest {
    public static String reverseString(String str) {
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            return str;
        } 
        //Calling Function Recursively
        return reverseString(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverseString("java"));
    }
}
```